# set effect for imageview in javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml, onhover

I have created a frame with some pictures in it. I would like to add a `glow effect` to the `button`'s in my `scence`, such that the `button`'s foreground gets brighter on *'mouse over'*.

##### Here is my **FXML** document:

```
public class FrameController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private GridPane album;
ImageView im;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

@FXML
private void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event.getSource());
    im = (ImageView) event.getSource();
    Glow selectGlow = new Glow(1.7f);
    im.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    im.setEffect(selectGlow);
    }
    });
}

}
```

but i have two problem:

1)It is very slow and sometimes it seems that mouse handler is not called when i am on a picture because effect does not change

2)I do not know which effect should i use in order to make picture darker when mouse enters pictures area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance depends on the effect. If you really only want to change the brightness, you could e. g. use [ColorAdjust](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html) like this:

```
public class ImageTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        Group root = new Group();

        Image image = new Image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/320px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");


        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        gridPane.add(createImageView( image), 0,0);
        gridPane.add(createImageView( image), 1,0);
        gridPane.add(createImageView( image), 0,1);
        gridPane.add(createImageView( image), 1,1);


        root.getChildren().add( gridPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ImageView createImageView( Image image) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
        colorAdjust.setBrightness(-0.5);

        imageView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> {

            imageView.setEffect(colorAdjust);

        });
        imageView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> {
            imageView.setEffect(null);
        });

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response, effect works fine but still takes a while to take effect, i mean when i am on a image i have to wait about one second to image become darker

Comment: what is your system? on mine it is instantly, no delay whatsoever.

Comment: i solved the problem, i was missed part of the code, thanks again